# Uploading image with form to related table

Tags: php, mysql

I can get my head around the best way to sort this problem.

I have a form that creates a new record in the database (using php and MySQL) this is all fine, but as part of this form I want the user to be able to upload some files. These files would be stored in another table within the DB (allowing multiple entries) and linking back to the original record.

I could upload the images on the next page, after the main record has been created, but really want this nice and simple, all on one form.

Another issue is that if the images are loaded into a temp place, before form submission, I don't want this images staying there forever if the form is left, or cancelled.

I am using [Fine uploader](http://fineuploader.com) to handle the file management, and php to save and place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use a temporary table / directory with a peridodic check-and-delete-old script?

Create a temp table with (id, identifier_key, data, timestamp), and delete old records from it periodiaccly using a cron script (or from your main web script, using a probability, like php's default session handler works - once in a 1000 request or something similar.)

Comment: Like the idea. I could also save a time to the temp DB when the file were uploaded, and if are still in temp DB they can be deleted after that time... Perfect. Will give it a go.